# error: expected initializer before ‘QtCoreModule’

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

Errors:

```
In file included from /opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:47,
                 from /opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtGui/qapplication.h:45,
                 from /opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtGui/QApplication:1,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/opt/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtCore/qeventloop.h:51: error: expected initializer before ‘QtCoreModule’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I have checked ; missing in my .h and .cpp files, couldn't find any. Should I post here the code? Or the error means something else?

Help!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm betting you're missing an `;` at the end of a class or struct declaration in one of the headers you're importing. (Your `MainWindow.h` specifically.)

```
class Whatever : ... {

}; // <- this ";" is crucial
```

Comment: Thanks Mat for asking such a dumb question...you saved me a ton of time